# ASP.Net C# CreateUserWizard Username, Password Properties

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, createuserwizard

Using ASP.Net Membership and CreateUserWizard, I noticed I am unable in code retrieve the values for Passoword, UserName, ConfirmPassword, etc. I am able to retieve extended extended properties.

Wondering if possible to retrieve UserName, etc. I have included sample code below. When the fields are filled in and postback, I am able to reference Password, ConfirmPassword, Email, and UserName, but the value received are empty strings. I am able to reach the Title field's value, which the Title field **doesn't** return an empty string. The code below is only a subset.

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="UserRegistration" runat="server" 
        onload="UserRegistration_Load" onprerender="UserRegistration_PreRender">
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="UserRegistrationStep_1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text="User Name"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="lblEMail" runat="server" Text="EMail"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="EMail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="lblConfirmPassowrd" runat="server" Text="Confirm Password"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassowrd" Text="1234567" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text="Title"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Title" Text="Title1234567" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="Captcha" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
            <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="UserRegistrationStep_2" runat="server">
            </asp:CompleteWizardStep>

        </WizardSteps>
    </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

**I placed the sample code in three different events:**

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s0 = ((TextBox)UserRegistration.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Password")).Text;
        string s1 = ((TextBox)UserRegistration.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Title")).Text;
        string s2 = ((TextBox)UserRegistration.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName")).Text;
        string s = s0+ s1 + s2;
    }

    protected void UserRegistration_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s0 = ((TextBox)UserRegistration.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Password")).Text;
        string s1 = ((TextBox)UserRegistration.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Title")).Text;
        string s2 = ((TextBox)UserRegistration.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName")).Text;
        string s = s0 + s1 + s2;
    }

    protected void UserRegistration_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s0 = ((TextBox)UserRegistration.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Password")).Text;
        string s1 = ((TextBox)UserRegistration.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Title")).Text;
        string s2 = ((TextBox)UserRegistration.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName")).Text;
        string s = s0 + s1 + s2;
    }
```

I am able to retrieve Title property in the Page_Load event, however UserName and Password returns an empty string in all three events.  Why is this?  How can I retrieve these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get the same via OnCreatedUser event.